# What are some good English translations of the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad

Tags: eastern-philosophy, self, translation

I have acquired a desire to read Brihadaranyaka Upanishad, but I do not read Sanskrit and I do not know which translations should be trusted. What are high quality translations of the Brihadaranyaka Upanishad?

Comment: I don't know if Eknath Easwaran has translated this, but he did translate some of the Upanishads and the Bhagavad Gita and I found his writing style admirable. I do not read Sanskrit either, so this is not an answer.

Comment: Here is the translation I have read. It has good reviews and appears to be popular: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0031ER4SS?ref_=r_sa_glf_b_0_hdrw_ss_AAu4AAA

Answer (score 1):

Here are the original texts, word by word translation, etymology and inner meanings of first two parts (Brahmins) of first chapter of Brihadaranyaka Upanishad.

https://upanishadsinenglish.blogspot.com/2019/11/p.html

https://upanishadsinenglish.blogspot.com/2019/11/brihadaaranyaka-upanishada-first.html

Answer (score 0):

This translation would be useful https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Brihadaranyaka-Upanishad.pdf

Prof: S Kuppuswami Sastri's introduction begins like this:

[image]

This link would be helpful to know more about Prof: S Kuppuswami Sastri http://worldcat.org/identities/lccn-n50067203/

Another useful translation is here: https://www.consciouslivingfoundation.org/ebooks/13/CLF-brihadaranyaka_upanishad.pdf

About the translator: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swami_Nikhilananda

Answer (score 0):

Any second hand language has limitations to exactly and accurately translate the eternal meaning of the Upnishadas (Vedas).

Any language translation has the four aspects of material errors (limitations) involved, namely, "bhrama", "pramada", "vipralipsa"& "karnapatava".

To realize the eternal knowledge of the Vedas and Upnishadas, is something sensing beyond these four errors.

We have gone through many translations available in the English, however, the best we found in the translated versions of Jagatguru Kripaluji's lectures in Vrindavan (Mathura, India). The selected verses of the Upnishadas we also found in the translations and purports by Srila A.C. Bhakti Vedanta Swami Prabhupada in ISKCON BBT Books.

The book form of the upnishada in English is also available with the Central Chinmaya Mission Trust, Mumbai. Adiguru Shankaracharya had said to a sanskrit scholar of varanasi, near the end of his life; "bhaj govindam, bhaj govindam, govindam bhaj moorkh/moodha mate..". His grace has explained all the Prime Upnishadas in his own style, however, in authoring the Gita-upnishada mahatmaya, he has said, "ekam shastram devaki-putra gitam...".

Best of luck !!

Comment: You wrote "we have gone through almost every translations available in the English". Who is "we"?

Comment: our group of associated devotees.